# Retrieving ListView using FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve two listviews from an ascx control for the purpose of saving them to a PDF file:

```
<TagCloud:TagCloudControl ID="TagCloudControl1" runat="server" />
```

I get the following error: TagCloudControl1 is a field but is used like a type and an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property...Thanks for your help!

```
ListView lv1 = (TagCloudControl1)ListView.FindControl("ListView1");
ListView lv2 = (TagCloudControl1)ListView.FindControl("ListView2");

lv1.RenderControl(htWriter);
lv2.RenderControl(htWriter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen or used a static `FindControl()` method.

[From MSDN for FindControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)

> Searches the current naming container
>   for a server control with the
>   specified id parameter.

Obviously if the listviews you are trying to locate are not in a Template, you should be able to access them directly in code-behind. But if it in a Template such as a GridView's Row then you can access it like this.

```
ListView listView1 = (ListView) GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("ListView1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be changed to this:

```
var lv1 = (TagCloudControl)ListView.FindControl("ListView1");
var lv2 = (TagCloudControl)ListView.FindControl("ListView2");
```

Comment: Hey, I updated my code and now it says: 'the type or namespace name TagCloudControl could not be found, and I'm still getting that object reference error...

Comment: @MiziaQ: Right-click on `TagCloudControl` and select **Resolve**, if you have referenced the correct assembly and the type of `ListView1` is `TagCloudControl`, it should give you an option by using or prefixing. I would use (ListView) anyway...